# Update year graph MRTG

Tags: mrtg

I have migrated my old 2.16 MRTG environment in a RHEL 6 machine to the new 2.17.4 a while ago and I keep having the same problem, my day, week and month graphs are updated as they should be with crontab but the year graph is not.

When I first updated the system I didn't copied from the begining all the images from /var/www/html/mrtg so they started to be generated and I also ran a cfgmaker to creat the new mrtg.cfg file. Then I copied my old mrtg.cfg file and also all the .png day, week, month and year pictures into /var/www/html/mrtg and I ran a indexmaker command to make the change happen and it does for one day. The year graphs are updated once a day but whenever the crontab does it the graph goes back to its old historical year graph which I had removed.

Does anybody know how could I make the change permanent? I haven't tried to recompile all MRTG but is going to be my next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the asnwer, "Each graph is build from the data in its own *.log and *.old files. So if you copy these to your production server you conserve all historic data from the test box. After the copy is complete you can start the MRTG process again."

It is well explained in this post:

https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/mrtg/2007-October/033185.html

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the graphs only get updated when they are "out-of-date" mrtg uses the time stamp on the image file to determine this. So you may want to make sure your year graph does not have an odd timestamp ...

you may also want to just move it away, then mrtg should re-generate it on the next run.